# How to filter data from table according to the column value MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need to fetch data from table according to the column value using PHP and MySQL. Here is my table:

db_area:

```
id      name        distance

1       Raj           4    
2       Kalia         5    
3       Golu          10    
4       Pretty        15    
5       raghu         12    
6       Sallu         20    
7       Malli          25    
8       Nalia          1700   
9        Bull          7  
10      Kullu           3
```

Here are some conditions:

```
< 5 km->index 0
5-10 km ->index 1
10-20 km->index 2
> 20 km->index 3
```

Here user has one input `i.e-$dist=0 or 1 or 2 or 3`. Here I need to fetch the data as per `$dist` value. If `$dist value is 0 then the data will fetch from table where distance column value is less than 5`. Similarly while `$dist=1` then the `data will fetch from table where distance is in between 5 and 10 KM` and so on.

Comment: See CASE, and make an attempt based upon what you discover

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch case statement for this as

```
$sql="select * from table Where 1=1 ";
switch ($dist) {
    case 0:
    $sql.=" and distance < 5";// for index 0
        break;
    case 1:
          $sql.=" and distance BETWEEN 5 and 10";
        break;
    case 2:
         $sql.=" and distance BETWEEN 10 and 20";
        break;
     case 3:
         $sql.=" and distance > 20";// greater then 20
        break;
    default:
         $sql=$sql;// default case
}
```

Comment: what is ` Where 1=1` and is this `distance BETWEEN 0 and 5` is valid to fetch the data ? Please clear it.

Comment: It nothing just equivalent to `select * from table`. For index 0 use can use `distance < 5`

Comment: I am implementing and let you know.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
switch($dist) {
    case '0':
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM db_area WHERE distance < 5";
    break;
    case '1':
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM db_area WHERE distance BETWEEN 5 AND 10";
    break;
    case '2':
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM db_area WHERE distance BETWEEN 10 AND 20";
    break;
    case '3':
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM db_area WHERE distance > 20";
    break;
    default:
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM db_area";
}
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: All `mysql_*` functions have been removed from the latest stable PHP version and no longer exist. Your code is outdated and likely to not work at all.

Comment: @Jocelyn I have just write a standard answer, Questioner can use this logic as per opensource or framework.

Comment: I agree with Jocelyn, and would advocate for the deletion of this answer.

Comment: @halfer, I answered this in 2016 and in 2021 you are advocating, how it is relevant?

Comment: @SumanSingh: questions and answers on Stack Overflow are for the long term - if they are good they are kept forever, like an encyclopaedia. They are thus open for answering, commenting, editing and curation forever also. Don't take it personally `:=)`